# Rails not recognizing Ruby's Net module

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to access the contents of the webpage of a target URL using the code:

```
def fetch_url(url)
    r = Net::HTTP.get_response( URI.parse( url ) )
    (r.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)) ? r.body : nil
end
```

However, for some reason Rails is not able to identify Net, which is a Ruby module from v. 1.9.2 -- why would this be (I used `require 'Net'` at the top of my code)?

> LoadError in PagesController#home
>
> no such file to load -- Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `require 'Net'`. You need this:

```
require 'net/http'
```

Comment: thanks!  I would accept the answer right now but Stack Overflow is making me wait 11 minutes before accepting.  but that worked :)